# TLS Handshake timeout in AWS ECR login

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssl, amazon-ecr, handshake

I'm trying to push docker image from my local machine CMD into AWS ECR. And for that first I'm trying to get the ECR login & password and then piping it into docker login. Below command is giving me error. Please advise.

aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin .dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Error - Error response from daemon: Get "https://.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/": net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the `aws_account_id` in you URI (which belongs before the `dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` part of the command you cite)

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: will try and let you know